# Why i getting error ? while injecting the Account class property using constructor in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

when i am running the code it is printing address of Accounnt class intead of account number.
Please  somebody help me.

// config class. i am not using xml.

package com.springcore.annotation.bean;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class EmpConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        Employee e1=new  Employee(101, "Diju Singh", "LabTechnician", 15000, setAccount());
        return e1;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Account  setAccount() {
        Account a1= new Account(1023450150);
        return a1;
    }

}


========================================================
```

//Test class
package com.springcore.annotation.bean;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class EmpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EmpConfig.class);
        Employee emp1= context.getBean("getEmployee", Employee.class);
        System.out.println(emp1);
        emp1.doWork();
        
    }

}
=======================================================================================
```

//Account bean class
package com.springcore.annotation.bean;

```
public class Account {
    
    private long accountNumber;

    public long getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(long accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public Account(long accountNumber) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    
}


============================================================
```

//Employee bean  class

```
package com.springcore.annotation.bean;

public class Employee {
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private double  salary;
    private Account  account;
    
    public Employee(int empId, String name, String department, double salary, Account account) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.account = account;
    }
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", name=" + name + ", department=" + department + ", salary=" + salary
                + ", account=" + account + "]";
    }
    
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("Employee is working ");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You will need `toString()` method for `Account` class similar to `Employee` class. Within `toString()` method of `Account` class, you can use `accountNumber` if you want to print that.

Comment: ohhh yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after writing toString() mehtod, it is working fine. I missed that